# MYSQL (SELECT under certain condition)

Tags: mysql

I'm a MYSQL Beginner and I have a Problem With A Query :

I have two tables ( **calls** , **callsfailed** ).

1. **calls** have these columns ( called_number, duration ).
2. **callsfailed** have these columns ( called_number, release_reason )

Lets Say **calls** Table is :

```
+---------------+----------+
| called_number | duration |
+---------------+----------+
| 1010101       | 13       |
| 1010101       | 18       |
| 1010101       | 20       |
| 2020202       | 50       |
| 2020202       | 20       |
| 3030303       | 10       |
| 4040404       | 30       |
+---------------+----------+
```

And **callsfailed** Table is :

```
+---------------+----------------+
| called_number | release_reason |
+---------------+----------------+
| 1010101       | -1             |
| 1010101       | -1             |
| 2020202       | -1             |
| 3030303       | 406            |
| 4040404       | 503            |
| 5050505       | -1             |
| 5050505       | -1             |
| 6060606       | -1             |
+---------------+----------------+
```

I want to select the called_number > 1, when it makes duration less than 25, OR it makes release_reason = -1. more than 1 time.

> **BUT** If the caller_number made a duration more than 25, don't select it even when it has a release_reason = -1.

So the result will be :

```
+---------------+-------+
| called_number | count |
+---------------+-------+
| 1010101       | 3     |
| 5050505       | 2     |
+---------------+-------+
```

MY CODE IS :

```
(  SELECT called_number, duration, COUNT(*) count 
   FROM calls 
   GROUP BY called_number 
   Having COUNT(called_number) > 1 and duration < 25 
) 

UNION 

( SELECT called_number, release_reason, COUNT(*) count 
  FROM callsfailed 
  GROUP BY called_number 
  Having COUNT(called_number) > 1 and release_reason = -1 
)
```

Comment: There's a bit of an issue with your tables: is there any relationship between the entries of one table, to another? For example, what if a number has both `-1` and something else (say `406`) as the `release_reason`, what should the outcome be?

Comment: It would focus on `-1` and just ignore `406` or any other reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UNION as derived table and select on it like this

```
SELECT t1.called_number, t1.count_calls FROM
(
    SELECT called_number, MAX(duration) max_duration, COUNT(called_number) count_calls 
    FROM calls 
    GROUP BY called_number 
    HAVING COUNT(called_number) > 1 AND max_duration < 25     

    UNION    

    SELECT called_number, release_reason, COUNT(called_number) count_callsfailed 
    FROM callsfailed 
    GROUP BY called_number 
    HAVING COUNT(called_number) > 1 AND release_reason = -1
) t1

GROUP BY t1.called_number
```

And you have your result

Comment: That is the closest answer thanks, but just one tiny problem, it gave me 2020202 ....... but 2020202 made duration more than 25 so i don't want it in the result .

Comment: You can see this sqlfield, it does not give me the 2020202 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83c879/1

Comment: YES, that helped me Thanks Dear :D

Answer (score 2):

Could be you are looking for a join

```
  select t1.called_number, t1.duration,  t1.count 
  from 

  (  SELECT called_number, duration, COUNT(*) count 
     FROM calls 
     GROUP BY called_number 
     Having COUNT(called_number) > 1 and duration < 25 
  ) t1

  left join 

  ( SELECT called_number, release_reason, COUNT(*) count 
    FROM callsfailed 
    GROUP BY called_number 
    Having COUNT(called_number) > 1 and release_reason = -1 
  )  t2 on t1.called_number = t2.called_number
```

But for the union could be you need where for duration e release_reason

```
      SELECT called_number, duration, COUNT(*) count 
      FROM calls 
      WHERE duration < 25 
      GROUP BY called_number 
      Having COUNT(called_number) > 1 

      union 

      SELECT called_number, release_reason, COUNT(*) count 
      FROM callsfailed 
      GROUP BY called_number 
      where release_reason = -1 
      Having COUNT(called_number) > 1
```

Comment: I Got This
[Err] 1052 - Column 'called_number' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: [Err] 1052 - Column 'count' in field list is ambiguous
:(

Comment: That answer Helped but it didn't gave me 5050505 which made a release_reason -1 more than once, but thanks anyway :)
I need the result to be as in the question..

Answer (score 1):

There are few gaps in the question.

1. In the expected result shouldn't the count for 1010101 be 5?
2. Other than the called_number is there any relationship between the
   entries in the two tables?
3. Your code has a very low probability to get you the result you want.

Here is my best guess about what you want to achieve

SELECT T1.called_number, (T1.C1 + T2.C2) AS count FROM (SELECT called_number, COUNT(*) AS C1 FROM calls WHERE duration < 25 GROUP BY called_number) T1
JOIN (SELECT called_number, COUNT(*) AS C2 FROM callsfailed WHERE release_reason = -1 GROUP BY called_number) T2 ON T1.called_number = T2.called_number 
WHERE (T1.C1 + T2.C2) > 1;

Comment: ( 1.The count won't matter i mean it must be more than 1 )

(2.duration and release_reason, they can be arranged from -1 to 25.)

(3.It gave me the same result as your code :( )

And Your Code Gave Me This Result :
[1010101 - 5]
[2020202 - 2], 

((BUT 2020202 Has made duration more than 25 !!!))

Comment: 1. Being thorough generally helps in life. 2. Your reply does not make any sense. 3. I cannot believe that your code and my code gave you the same result.

Comment: Your result 
+---------------+----------+-------+
| called_number | duration | count |
+---------------+----------+-------+
|       1010101 |       13 |     3 |
|       1010101 |       -1 |     2 |
|       5050505 |       -1 |     2 |
+---------------+----------+-------+

Comment: My Result
+---------------+-------+
| called_number | count |
+---------------+-------+
|       1010101 |     5 |
|       2020202 |     2 |
+---------------+-------+

Comment: No Dear, it gave me the same result, i mean it didn't help :). i need the query to give me result as in the question, 
+---------------+-------+
| 1010101       | 3     |
| 5050505       | 2     |
+---------------+-------+

Comment: And as i told : i'm a beginner so a simple answer would help :D